# Is there a way to hide from imperial troops?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Sometimes I just looking for a piece of ore and hear one of my teammates say 'Imperial ship above!", and, a few minutes later, that ship will drop a few soldiers on my face.

Is there anything to do to 'dodge' that encounter? It feels like there would be a way to hide from imperial troops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to avoid these encounters is to run away. Near the end of the game, I was running around to find side quests and earn trophies, so these encounters were quite cumbersome. Simply running away will leave them confused and wandering around until you get far enough for them to despawn.